# How to get a sequence of five inputs of colors. Color should be only Red,Green and Blue need a pattern of colors.Programming in Java?

Tags: java

Do I need extra loop for colors and how? Full Problem is A designer is trying to create a new pattern of five stripes using three colors. These colors and their codes are mentioned in the table below. Color Character Code Red R Green G Blue B The designer has to keep in mind that no two adjacent stripes are of the same color. For example, RRGBR is an invalid pattern, but RGBRB is valid. Write a program that accepts a sequence of five colors as input from the designer to form the pattern. At each selection the designer makes, the program should check if the input is from among the available set of colors. Also, the program should check that adjacent colors are not the same. At the end, the program should display the final stripe pattern created.

```
public class Colors {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Input.");
        String color;
        int counter = 0;
        do {
            color = scannerObject.next();
            System.out.println("Your selection is :" + color);
            counter++;
        } while (counter < 5);

        scannerObject.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You code shows how you read the color as an input, but you have no code to run any checks. Please [edit] your question to include your code/attempts on how to run the checks for adjacent colors.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have an array (e.g. `desiredCombination[]` in the code given below) to store the valid inputs.
2. You can have a `List` (e.g. `List<String> allowedColors` in the code given below) or array of allowed colours with which you need to validate the input colour.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scannerObject = new Scanner(System.in);
        String color;
        int counter = 0;
        List<String> allowedColors = List.of("R", "G", "B");
        String[] desiredCombination = new String[5];
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter a color [R/G/B]: ");
            color = scannerObject.nextLine();

            // There is no element before desiredCombination[0] and therefore the colour for
            // desiredCombination[0] does not require comparing with the one before it.
            if (counter == 0 && allowedColors.contains(color.toUpperCase())) {
                desiredCombination[counter++] = color;
            } else if (allowedColors.contains(color.toUpperCase()) && !color.equals(desiredCombination[counter - 1])) {
                desiredCombination[counter++] = color;
            }
        } while (counter < 5);
        System.out.println("The desired combination is: " + Arrays.toString(desiredCombination));
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter a color [R/G/B]: R
Enter a color [R/G/B]: R
Enter a color [R/G/B]: G
Enter a color [R/G/B]: B
Enter a color [R/G/B]: R
Enter a color [R/G/B]: R
Enter a color [R/G/B]: B
The desired combination is: [R, G, B, R, B]
```

**An important note:** Never close `Scanner` for `System.in` as it will also close `System.in` and you won't have any way to open it again.

Comment: You can close a System.in Scanner at the end of your application, when you're sure you don't need it anymore.  Any Java application should have one and only one System.in Scanner defined.

Comment: Thanks, @GilbertLeBlanc for the feedback. The application may have many classes and therefore it will always be error-prone to close `Scanner` for `System.in` in one or more of those classes. JDBC objects or `Scanner` for a file or any such objects which may have large memory footprint have been designed in such a way that they should be closed after use and opened again when required. The `Scanner` object of `System.in` has negligible memory footprint and it should be left to the JVM to be closed. However, if the application has just one class, closing the `Scanner` for `System.in` is safe.